# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object when converting raster file to csv file

Tags: python, raster, csv, raster-conversion

I want to convert a raster file to csv file. When I use `raster2xyz`, my code raises `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object` error.

```
from raster2xyz.raster2xyz import Raster2xyz
from skimage import io

benign1_img = io.imread("/content/drive/MyDrive/benign/ytma10_010704_benign1.TIF")
benign1_csv = "benign1.csv"
rtxyz = Raster2xyz()
rtxyz.translate(benign1_img, benign1_csv)
```

Traceback:

```
> [2021-10-22 09:37:43 - INFO] - Getting geotransform and data...
> [2021-10-22 09:37:43 - ERROR] - Error getting geotransform and data:
> not a string
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-8-26914c895975> in <module>()
>       1 rtxyz = Raster2xyz()
>       2 
> ----> 3 rtxyz.translate(benign1_img, benign1_csv)
>       4 rtxyz.translate(benign2_img, benign2_csv)
>       5 rtxyz.translate(benign3_img, benign3_csv)
> 
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/raster2xyz/raster2xyz.py in
> translate(self, input_raster, out_xyz, no_data, n_band, rnd)
>     129         """
>     130         """
> --> 131         gtr, raster_values = self.__getRasterData(input_raster, n_band)
>     132 
>     133         if not no_data:
> 
> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Comment: Don't open it with skimage, a non-geospatial library. Just pass the file path as per the documentation  `rtxyz.translate(path_to_tif, benign1_csv)`